# CSS Transform rotate not working in my code

Tags: html, css

I tried to create the CSS3 transform simple demos, i got struck as i am not able to see the element is rotating when i use `transform:rotate(180deg)`

see the codepen:http://codepen.io/shmdhussain/pen/yYMWba

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box transz"></div>
<div class="box rotatex"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.transz {
    /*Translate Z transform*/
    transform: translate3d(100px, 200px, 100px);
}

.rotatex {
    transform: rotate( 180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused as to your confusion. For me, your codepen works just fine. The rotate transformation takes the original shape and rotates it one time by the number of degrees you specify. In your case, you're just rotating a square by 90/180/270 degrees, which will look identical to the original. If you rotate by something like 45 degrees, you should see a result. Apologies if there is a more complex problem I'm not seeing!

Comment: got confused in simple calc, sorry for that. Got it. any clue about transition on z-axis transform: translate3d(100px, 200px, 100px);

Comment: Moreover I am using the perfect square so that only I am not able to see the rotation in 90,270 deg. Got the point. any help in translate3d

Comment: No problem, but what do you mean? What behavior are you looking for from that transform? The code you have there should just move your square a little bit.

Comment: Is translate3d is working on my code? ... is there any value in z-axis to easily perceive the changes

Comment: I think we need perspective and transform style to do that.

Comment: I'm not completely sure without looking into it more, but I think that translate3d is working as well. It seems to be visibly moving your block in the x and y directions, and in the z direction there is nothing for it to overlap/go behind, so it looks the same. If you made two squares, one blue and one red, and made them overlap slightly, I think a transform3d in the z-axis would show one above the other. As for getting a realistic 3D perspective where the object shrinks as it goes further away, it's definitely possible but I'm not sure how.